# Define Parameter in Object conditionally

Tags: javascript, object, syntax-error, declaration

I am using a framework7 calendar and in declaring the calendar I need to set the value based upon the current date value in the input that is dynamically generated with php. This works, but the problem is that when a date is not set the empty string should not define the date as Dec. 31, 1969. I have tried sending a null value based upon an if statement but it does not work either. The only way the function will work is if a valid date is set or the parameter is not set altogether. The question is how to change the following to declare the value parameter only if it is not empty or null.

```
    if($('input[name=session-date]').val()!=""){
        sessionDate = Date.parse($('input[name=session-date]').val());
        alert("sessionDate set");
    } else {
        sessionDate = null;
        alert("sessionDate NOT set");
    }
    //define call to calendar function with parameters
    var calendarInline = myApp.calendar({
        value: [sessionDate],
        //etc.,
    });
```

I have tried:

```
    if($('input[name=session-date]').val()!=""){
        sessionDate = Date.parse($('input[name=session-date]').val());
        alert("sessionDate set");
    } else {
        sessionDate = null;
        alert("sessionDate NOT set");
    }
    //define call to calendar function with parameters
    var calendarInline = myApp.calendar({
        if(sessionDate){
            value: [sessionDate],
        }
        //etc.,
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set an object parameter conditionally inside the object definition, but you can do an IIFE inside `myApp.calendar`, that returns your object, like this:

```
var calendarInline = myApp.calendar((function() {
    var obj = {
        //values...
    }

    if(sessionDate) {
        obj.value = [sessionDate];
    }

    return obj;

})())
```

Or, you can create and conditionally construct your object before initializing `calendarInline`, and then just pass the object to `myApp.calendar()`

Comment: Cannot? I did... and it works. Do you have any reference where this is not allowed or any examples of browsers versions where this is not allowed/does not work?

Comment: @amaster507 As Felix said in a comment to your answer, what you are using doesn't do what you think. ES6 concise methods (https://blog.getify.com/es6-concise-methods-lexical-or-not/) is the feature which enables you to do that (I do not have enabled in my browser this feature apparently). The answer remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can call a function with a default value. In ES6 you have default values for arguments or in ES5 you can use some logical short circuits. So first you create a wrapper function to call your library method.

in ES6 you can do like;

```
var celendarCall = function(sd = myBirthDay) {myApp.calendar({value:[sd],...})},
  calendarInline = calendarCall(sessionDate);
```

so if you don't provide an argument to `calendarCall` it will use `myBirthDay` as the default value.

Or in ES 5 you can do the same like

```
var celendarCall = function(sd) {myApp.calendar({value:[sd],...})},
  calendarInline = calendarCall(sessionDate || myBirthDay);
```

so if `sessionDate` is `undefined` or anything falsey it will use `myBirthDay` as the default argument to call the `calendarCall` function.